# Why the pod status is coming as crashloopbackoff in my case?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I created a pod which just calculates the pi and exits and it should run again. On monitoring I observed the status was running, then turned completed and finally crashloopbackoff .

I tried different images, but issue is the same.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
    containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]

Running and Completed status in a series. But i see CrashLoopBackOff.
qvamjak@qvamjak:~/Jobs$ kubectl get pods
NAME           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pi             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   16         63m
```

Comment: Try the command `kubectl describe po <podname> -n <namespace>` and towards the end you will find events , the reason would be there , you can paste the output for further help.

Also in order to reliably run one Pod to completion you should use  kubernetes Jobs. THat will create pod in Completed status. Read more here 
[link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/)

Comment: qvamjak@qvamjak:~$ kubectl describe pod pi
Name:         pi
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:   Sat, 07 Sep 2019 09:21:40 +0530
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.7
Containers:
  pi:
    Container ID:  docker://547366e6b4b3593eb87e513ae6aae4623de85ba7e64b53603f84c95cf7d968ba
    Image:         perl
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://perl@sha256:5cada8a3709c245b0256a4d986801e598abf95576eb01767bde94d567e23104e
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>

Comment: Command:
      perl
      -Mbignum=bpi
      -wle
      print bpi(2000)
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 07 Sep 2019 11:40:43 +0530
      Finished:     Sat, 07 Sep 2019 11:40:47 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  31
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-62tcf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status

Comment: Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------   ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  BackOff  34s (x617 over 140m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: Please find the output .

Comment: By default the pods have a restartpolicy of Always and it is advised the pods that are expected to terminate must have a restart policy of Never or OnFailure .
SO you can either add this field to your yaml `apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  containers:
  - name: pi
    image: perl
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: '1'
        memory: 1Gi
      limits:
        cpu: '1'
        memory: 1Gi
    command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
  restartPolicy: Never`

or you can make it a k8s Job

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `restartPolicy` of your pod, by default it is `Always`, which means the pod expects all its containers to be long-running (e.g., HTTP server), if any container in the pod exits (even successfully with code 0), it will be restarted. In this case, you want to set `restartPolicy` as `OnFailure`. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy.

In addition to that, [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) instead of Pod is the resource type you want for run-to-completion applications, because Job manages pods for you and offers more guarantees than unmanaged Pod.

Comment: I tried with onFailure and it's showing as completed now. But the question is when the default is Always, the status should be  Running and Completed right ? Why crashloopback is coming during the restart is the question?

Comment: restartPolicy=Always means the Pod expects the container to be long-running (e.g., HTTP server), even if it exits with code 0, it is considered as "crash".